# How to transform / remap URLs using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want a redirection in my website.

The old url looks like this :

http://www.example.com/Prem_Ratan_Dhan_Payo/Prem_Leela.html

Now we have to 301 redirect it to

http://example.com/songs/prem-leela/

In total I have to

1. Check if the url end with .html then we will redirect it other wise let it pass.
2. remove .html from end.
3. make all letters in lower case.
4. change underscore to hyphen.
5. change second segment to 'songs'.

Please help me.

Comment: some points I can manage but stuck on first point for condition check if the re is .html or not. If .html is not there the the whole thing should stop.

Comment: This is basically a simple end-of-string regex. Take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html for the whole thing.

Comment: I'm very bad @ regex ... :( ... tried this one a lot but ... no luck ....

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Replace underscores with hyphens in all requests ending in .html.
# The rule replaces one char at a time and is repeated until no matches are found.
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "\.html$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N]

# Capture the file name without extension inside braces
# Use a lower-case mapping on the file name.
# Destination is /songs/filename
RewriteMap lc int:tolower 
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)\.html$ /songs/${lc:$1} [NC, R=301]
```